# Regular expression to match words which does not start with particular charector in python using negative lookahead assertion

Tags: python, regex

In the string

```
s = 'Makeupby Antonia #makeup #makeupartist #makeupdolls #abhcosmetics'
```

I want to match only word which does not start with `#`. Means I want to select only `Makeupby` and `Antonia`
I tried using negative lookahead assertion

```
re.findall(r'\b(?![#])[a-zA-Z]+',s)  

['Makeupby',
 'Antonia',
 'makeup',
 'makeupartist',
 'makeupdolls',
 'abhcosmetics']
```

But this is matching with all words. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!)` is syntax for a negative lookahead. You want a negative lookbehind.

try `\b(?<!#)[a-zA-Z]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/21)